# Can you use WP Query with SHORTINIT?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So my admin-ajax function was really slow. I've used SHORTINIT and been able to echo some raw html onto the page where I want my results to show. So I know that the ajax/javascript is working.

Problem is, the function I want to execute is to find products in a specific category within WooCommerce.

I'm declaring the below code at the top of my "ajax url" which I have set in my javascript file...

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
```

I get the following error: Fatal error: Class 'WP_Query' not found in web_url on line 10.

There must be a way to be able to do this, has anybody else been successful?

Thanks in advance.